# FFMPEG : Capture and Stream from Android Mobile Camera

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am checking for how we can use ffmpeg command line in android like using WritingMinds ffmpeg compiled for Android or any other Git project.

I am trying to set following command:

-loglevel trace -f android_camera -camera_index 0 -video_size hd720 -framerate 30 -input_queue_size 2 -i discarded -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -y /sdcard/editor_input/out.mp4"

But it gives Unrecognized option 'camera_index'.

There are some project like "https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder" which has Recorder App to store MP4 file but they seems uses FFMPEG APIs and code for getting frames and all, I Just want to directly use ffmpeg as commandline like we use in Linux.

Can someone please guide what is best way to capture from android camera and stream MPEGTS stream on UDP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In React Native you can use react-native-ffmpeg-kit